# Export XLSX in Odoo 16

Tags: odoo, xlsx

I'm using OCA module "excel_import_export".

I want to add logo of company in excel report ,I'm trying with this code , but still have problem.

```
 <field name="input_instruction">
            {
                '__EXPORT__': {
                    'sale_order': {
                        '_HEAD_': {
                            'B1': base64.b64decode((company_id.logo${value and  or ""})),
                           
            ....
        </field>
```

Any help please?